# Angularjs Pass all attributes on a directive to the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building a tiny angular directive `<my-input>` on top of a normal HTML `<input>`.

And because this is going to be available in a framework, I need to allow people to pass whichever attribute they might use from the directive to the input element. For example:

`<my-directive disabled="disabled" type="email">`

would render

`<input disabled="disabled" type="email">`

I know that if I have a static list of attributes, I can manually do it.. but the problem is I can't predict what attributes will be added.. so I'm looking for a solution that passes **all** the attributes from the directive to the input element.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use attribute directive over existing `input`? Some code would make it more clear.

Comment: hmm what do you mean? It's just the `my-directive` code here that passed the `disabled` and `type` attributes.. but without binding it to only disabled and type..

Comment: I mean `<input my-directive disabled="disabled" type="email">`.

Comment: You can provide your own functionality in an attribute directive. People can use the same input tag and add your directive as needed. Would that work for you?

Comment: oh okay, because the view is a bit more complex than that, for example it contains a wrapper with some classes.. so it wouldn't work

Comment: The question doesn't reflect your needs. Again, some code may help a lot.

Comment: Okay I'll add a codepen first thing in the morning. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple attributes to the view, you can perform it into the **link** function.

Here is your directive :

**Directive**

```
(function(){

  function myInput($compile) {
      return{
          restrict: 'E',
          templateUrl: 'template.html',
          link: function(scope, elm, attrs){

            //Convert camelCase to dash
            function toDash(str) {
               return str.replace(/\W+/g, '-')
                         .replace(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2');
            }

            //Retrieve input into the template
            var input = angular.element(document.querySelector('#myInput'));

            //Loop on attrs
            for (var key in attrs) {
              if (key[0] !== '$'){
                //Remove all attribute to the top level element
                elm.removeAttr(toDash(key));

                //Add our attribute to the input
                input.attr(toDash(key), attrs[key]);

                //Compile and link it to the scope
                $compile(input)(scope);
              }
            }

          }
        };
  }

angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('myInput', myInput);


})();
```

With the template :

**template.html**

```
<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

For example, in a controller you can set some variable :

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope) {

  $scope.show = true;

  $scope.toto = 'Hello !!'

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

And call your directive :

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

    <my-input disabled="disabled" ng-model="toto" ng-show="show"></my-input>

   </body>
```

So it will remove all attributes to the `my-input` element, and set it into your template.

Comment: Great thanks!
I'd just remove this `var input = angular.element(document.querySelector('#myInput'));` in favor of `elm[0]`

Comment: Would it not be better to run the `$compile()` once after the `for` loop is finished?

Comment: Indeed, it should be a good improvement ! I did not pay attention :)

Comment: I've been having issues with this code if any of the attributes are directives. ```Multiple directives asking for new/isolated scope on: ...```. Any idea on a workaround?